# ActionView::Template::Error missing on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, renderpartial

I follow http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised?view=comments
to complete the ajax on Rails course.
but I totally confused.

in the controller, it fetch two kinds of task.

```
controllers/tasks_controller.rb
4:    @incomplete_tasks = Task.where(complete: false)
5:    @complete_tasks = Task.where(complete: true)
```

and render it in index.html.erb by

```
views/tasks/index.html.erb
6:<div class="tasks" id="incomplete_tasks">
7:  <%= render @incomplete_tasks %>
11:<div class="tasks" id="complete_tasks">
12:  <%= render @complete_tasks %>
```

also you can append a new task by

```
views/tasks/create.js.erb
3:$('#incomplete_tasks').append('<%= j render(@task) %>');
```

however , there is no _incomplete_task.html.erb and _complete_task.html.erb , so how could rails know what to render.

it confuse me totally.
please give me some directions, thanks~

```
[tasks] $ ls
_form.html.erb* create.js.erb*  index.html.erb* new.js.erb*
_task.html.erb* destroy.js.erb* new.html.erb*   update.js.erb*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the partials explicitly:

```
views/tasks/index.html.erb
6:<div class="tasks" id="incomplete_tasks">
7:  <%= render partial: 'task', collection: @incomplete_tasks %>
11:<div class="tasks" id="complete_tasks">
12:  <%= render partial: 'task', collection: @complete_tasks %>
```

and

```
views/tasks/create.js.erb
3:$('#incomplete_tasks').append('<%= j render(partial: 'task', object: @task) %>');
```